# Как вернуть SELECT запрос из функции?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Нужно создать функцию, которая позволит вернуть тот же результат, что и запрос `SELECT`, и которая могла бы содержать PL/SQL код.

Пробую нечто действительно простое:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN l_rc FOR 
    SELECT * FROM tab;
  RETURN l_rc;
END;
/
```

Но когда вызываю эту функцию запросом:

```
SELECT foo FROM dual;
```

Получаю все результаты из таблицы в одной ячейке, а не каждый столбец отдельно:

> {<ID=1,NAME=name 1>,<ID=2,NAME=name 2>,<ID=3,NAME=name 3>,}

Есть ли способ вывести результат функции в табличной форме?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can I return a SELECT query with an oracle function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67776791) от участника [@Natty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7684768/natty)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67776791

Comment: А надо именно в таком виде? Table function не подойдет?

Comment: @МаринаАрхипцева В каком таком виде вы имеете ввиду? Что-то в вопросе непонятно?

Comment: Вопрос снимается, не заметила, что это перевод )

Comment: @МаринаАрхипцева Почему вопрос снимается? Перевод это "не заразно", можно ещё ответов настрочить. Или вы отвечаете только "реальным" авторам?

Comment: Конечно не заразно ) В оригинальном посте уже ответили хорошими ответами, не буду повторяться

Answer (score 4):

Функция возвращяет открытый курсор. Как результат его выполнения выводится, полностью зависит от клиентского ПО или IDE, где эта функция вызывается.

Например, Курсор, полученый через преременную подстановки, так же выводится в виде таблицы:

```
create table tab (id, name) as
    select rownum, 'name '||rownum from dual connect by level<=3 
/
create or replace function TabById (id int) return sys_refcursor is
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for 
        select * from tab where id=TabById.id;
    return rc;
end;
/

var rc refcursor
exec :rc := TabById (1);
print rc

        ID NAME                                         
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 name 1
```

В более новых версиях SQL*Plus, SQL Developer курсор, полученый как столбец в SQL запросe, выводится так же в виде таблицы:

```
SQL> select TabById (1) from dual;

TABBYID(1)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

        ID NAME
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 name 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Для задачи как в вопросе -- вывести результат определённого запроса, и иметь возможность его предварительно обработать, хорошо подойдёт такое решение: поместить определение курсора в спецификацию пакета, и на его основе добавить в пакет конвейерную функцию.

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
create or replace package pack as
    cursor cur (id int) is
        select * 
        from tab where id=cur.id;
    type resty is table of tab%rowtype;  
    function TabById (id int) return resty pipelined;
end;
/
create or replace package body pack as
    function TabById (id int) return resty pipelined is
        r tab%rowtype;
    begin
        open cur (id);
        loop fetch cur into r;
            exit when cur%notfound;
            r.name := '*'||r.name;
            pipe row (r);
        end loop;
        return;
    end;
end;
/
```

Запрос и вывод результата:

```
select * from pack.TabById (1);

        ID NAME                                         
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 *name 1
```