# Как вернуть результаты запроса из функции если SQL формируется динамически?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

В функции динамически формируется запрос, как можно вернуть его результаты из функции?
Проблема в том, что кол-во столбцов в запросе каждый раз может быть разным и поэтому нельзя объявить тип-структуру чтобы возвратить результаты. [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1289567/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-select-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) связанный вопрос, но там заранее определена структура.

Comment: Почитай про dbms_sql

Comment: По ссылке в вопросе второй ответ как раз предлагает решение, где структура результата запроса заранее не определена. Почему это решшение вам не помогло?

Comment: Потому что во втором решении используется заранее созданная и определённая структура в виде таблицы "tab" - "type resty is table of tab%rowtype;"

Comment: @Pithein dbms_sql работает только начиная с версии 12.1

Comment: Там используется таблица только для примера. Вы можете там написать динамический запрос с любой структурой результата этого запроса.

Comment: Но ведь это в объявлении пакета всё написано, как туда можно перезаписывать динамический запрос?

Comment: В смысле, что написано и в каком пакете?

Comment: create or replace package pack as
    cursor cur (id int) is
        select * 
        from tab where id=cur.id;

Comment: Я же дал простой пример того, что вы хотите, в ответе ниже. Там нет никаких пакетов.

Comment: Я думал вы про второе решение говорите. В вашем решении "exec :rc := foo (3,2)" надо вручную перечислить и указать количество столбцов, т.е. надо задавать заранее структуру.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, прямо в вопросе пример запроса, где вы не задаёте структуру его результата.

Comment: Например поворот таблицы, из строк в столбцы. Количество столбцов получаю и собираю динамическим запросом, оно соответственно может меняться.

Comment: Покажите _прямо_ в вопросе или на фиддле, как выглядит ваш запрос.

Comment: Dbms_sql вам в помощь

Answer (score 3):

Следуя формулировке вопроса, скорее всего, как в минимальном примере:

```
create table t (dt) as
    select to_date (column_value, 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt 
    from xmlTable ('"2022-03-06","2022-04-04"') 
/
set autoprint on 
create or replace function mons return sys_refcursor is
    cols varchar2 (32767);
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    for r in (select rownum rn, to_char (dt, 'Mon') mon from t order by dt) loop
        cols := cols||r.rn||' '||r.mon||',';
    end loop;
    open rc for 'select '||rtrim (cols, ',')||' 
                 from dual';
    return rc;
end;
/
```

Результат будет выглядеть так:

```
var rc refcursor
exec :rc := mons ()

       MAR        APR
---------- ----------
         1          2

insert into t values (date'2022-01-01')
/
exec :rc := mons ()

       JAN        MAR        APR
---------- ---------- ----------
         3          1          2
```

Comment: Цитата из вашего комментерия: _В вашем решении "exec :rc := foo (3,2)" надо вручную перечислить и указать количество столбцов_. Это не так, запрос польностью динамический. Попытался улучшить   пример. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, так более понятно.

Answer (score 0):

> В функции динамически формируется запрос, как можно вернуть его результаты из функции?

Через temporary table.

> ```
> create function test ()
> returns int deterministic
> begin
> drop temporary table if exists tmp;
> create temporary table tmp (id int);
> insert into tmp values (10), (20);
> return 1;
> end
> ```

> ```
> SELECT test();
> SELECT * FROM tmp;
> ```
>
> ```
> | test() |
> | -----: |
> |      1 |
>
> | id |
> | -: |
> | 10 |
> | 20 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b0ae4219ac035a7347032ae32c78200)*

Comment: Я в тегах указал oracle, там такое можно? И тут ведь надо указывать столбцы, я писал "кол-во столбцов в запросе каждый раз может быть разным".

Comment: @Merlin *Я в тегах указал oracle* [link1](https://habr.com/ru/post/119996/), [link2](https://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=26:11949), [link3](https://oracle-patches.com/db/sql/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-sql-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-pl-sql). А для возврата именно динамической структуры... вот что-то вряд ли. Да и как ты собираешься недетерминированную структуру использовать в запросе?

Comment: во всех 3 ссылках везде заранее созданные структуры с фиксированным набором полей:
type rowGetEmployees is record( фиксированное кол-во поля.. или CREATE TYPE pet_t IS OBJECT ( фиксированные поля.. Ладно подождём, вдруг кто-то знает

Comment: А тебе правда надо именно table-type output? ты хочешь использовать функцию в секции FROM запроса как источник данных?

Comment: очень не хочется формировать вручную печать результатов, если конечно подскажете как без лишних телодвижений вывести результаты запроса, то буду признателен.

Comment: А ответить на заданный вопрос? Вот тебе точно нужна **функция**? Хранимая процедура - точне НЕ подойдёт?

Comment: Какой вопрос, вот этот? "как ты собираешься недетерминированную структуру использовать в запросе?" Мне надо просто вывести её, но только средствами pl/sql или sql, можно и процедурой.